# copy selected values of rows that check box selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type = "checkbox" name = "chk"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select name = "foo">
            <option value = "1">One</option>
            <option value = "2">Two</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select name = "bar">
            <option value = "1">One</option>
            <option value = "2">Two</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
        <input type = "checkbox" name = "chk"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select name = "foo">
            <option value = "1">One</option>
            <option value = "2">Two</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select name = "bar">
            <option value = "1">One</option>
            <option value = "2">Two</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I want to clone the row with selected items whose check box is checked.

I was using this but it is only copying the text fields and not the selected items.

```
lastRow = $('#dataTable tr').has('input:checked').html();
$('#dataTable tr:last').after('<tr>'+lastRow+'</tr>');
$('#dataTable tr:last').find('select').each(function()
{
    var this_select=$(this);
    this_select.val(this_select.closest('tr').prev().find('td:eq('+this_select.closest('td').index()+')').find('select').val());
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like

```
var srcrow = $('#dataTable tr').has('input:checked');
var lastRow = srcrow.clone();

lastRow.find('select').each(function(idx, el){
    var $el = $(el);
    $el.val(srcrow.find('select').eq(idx).val())
});

$('#dataTable tr:last').after(lastRow);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/T7epC/2/)

A little more complicated implementation which support for multiple checked items

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/T7epC/)

Comment: @Arun P Johny : How do I store the individual column values of the selected row into different variables .